# Just synced a node, but want to use docker instead, can I moved synced db into container?

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync, docker

I just synced a node using geth fastsync and it took several days.

But I just decided I want to use this computer's resources differently and run my ethereum environment from a docker container

I like the prebuilt ones, but even if I compose an environment myself, is there any way to prevent resyncing from scratch? Perhaps a way to copy geth's parsed blocks and states into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to mount a host path to a container. If your synced database is stored in `/home/foo/.ethereum` for example, you can mount it to the Geth docker container with:

```
$ docker run -it -p 30303:30303 -v /home/foo/.ethereum:/root/.ethereum ethereum/client-go
```

Do not change `/root/.ethereum`, since that's where the folder will be mounted inside the container.